Move PGEC2/PGED2 to PGEC1/PGED1 on PIC32MX
I have a board with PIC32MX795F512L. The board icsp connector is connected to PGEC1 (pin 24) and PGED1 (pin 25). I accidentaly flashed a hex bootloader (i don't have the source code) used for another project. This bootloader moves programming pins to PGEC2 (pin 26) and PGED2 (pin 27). So now I can't program the pic32 anymore using MPLAB IPE; i can only flash an hex using the bootloader + usb method.
Which code should I write to change PGEC2/PGED2 back to PGEC1/PGED1?

You should write bit 3 ICESEL of the DEVCFG0 register to zero, according to the datasheet.

Here you have some information regarding how to self-write the DEVCFG registers, which is otherwise normally only written by the programmer: https://forum.microchip.com/s/topic/a5C3l000000MaS3EAK/t370179
